# relocatable dylibs (e.g. embedded frameworks) are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later (@rpath/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

I just upgraded from Xcode 6 Beta 2 to Xcode Beta 3 and am now getting the following warning when building my project:

```
ld: warning: relocatable dylibs (e.g. embedded frameworks) are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later (@rpath/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib)
```

It is a warning but seems to mean my current setup will not work on iOS 7.1, which is my deployment target. How can I track down which frameworks are embedded, and how can I fix this for iOS < 8.0?

Comment: Check Klingers answer [on this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623831/error-when-debugging-on-7-1-device-swift-xcode6-beta-3

Comment: I'm getting that warning too, but I'm still able to test apps on my iOS 7.1 device.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This appears to be a bug of Beta 3. As pointed out by Apple Engineer on this [post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/999579#999579).

I have also been living with this warning when running apps on iOS 7.1 device.

Comment: Also note @Dennis Munsie made nice assertion.

Comment: The bug still exists in Beta 4

Comment: Gladly this bug is fixed in **Beta 5**.

Comment: i don't think you can run on iOS7 if using Xcode6 GM version.

Comment: Came across this in the Xcode 6.1.1 preview, wasn't a problem in 6.1.

Comment: The Apple link is broken.

Answer (score 4):

You see and add them on the project page when you select the target: tab *General->Embedded Binaries* (and they then appear in *Build Phases->Embed Frameworks*).

[image: Example of embedded frameworks]

Embedded frameworks **for OSX** were available in Xcode 5, but **not for iOS**.

WWDC session regarding new features in Xcode 6 specifically promised dynamic frameworks for iOS 8 (someone please add citation when developer center comes back online). So far, with all Xcode 6 betas, I have had no problems compiling and debugging an app with frameworks on iOS 7.

But since this wasn't promised, **frameworks for iOS7 is something you cannot depend on** (e.g. this may stop working in later betas; an app with embedded framework for iOS 7 may be rejected, etc.). That may explain why they added an explicit warning.

There's not much you can do if this feature turns out to be indeed unsupported, other than remove the frameworks from the target and use static libraries as we did with Xcode 5. Or go the iOS8-only route.

Comment: I am getting the same thing but I have nothing bundled,

Comment: I have no Embedded Binaries but still see the warning.

Comment: I don't have any Embedded Binaries either and I still get the same warning as masters3d and Pang.

Comment: The error message specifically says libswift_stdlib_core.dylib.  This would seem to be caused by the Swift runtime being included in the app.  Since Apple has already said that iOS 7 will be a supported target for Swift apps, this is probably just a bug in the beta. A bug report would probably be appreciated.

Comment: My project also gives the warning.But it is running perfectly in iOS7 device.Will it be rejected by iTunes application loader? 
If yes how to implement embedded frameworks in iOS7.

Answer (score 1):

After using XCode 6.1.1 I am able to put the code on iOS 8+ iOS7.1.2 and iOS 6.1.3 Although the warning is still there but the app works absolutely fine on all the 3 OSs

======================
Lucky guy... My project keeps failing to compile after I referenced the PushKit framework.

The project is a new project created by Xcode with only 3 new functions for testing Push Notification.

The workaround is to put the PushKit framework as "embedded", but this is not a good solution since my working Xcode project will be generated from Unity3d. Making the changes manually will break the auto build process.

Comment: You should post comments as such and not as anwesers for the question.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after adding a C++ framework (DeepBelief) to a project. Adding an empty .cpp file to the project fixed it.

I'm using Beta4, and found the answer on the DeepBelief github site:

> [XCode may be skipping the standard C++ library, and that's needed by
>   the DeepBelief.framework code. One workaround I've found is to include
>   an empty .mm or .cpp file in the project to trick XCode into treating
>   it as a C++
>   project.](https://github.com/jetpacapp/DeepBeliefSDK#adding-to-an-existing-ios-application)

Answer (score 0):

Read this github post from [ReactiveCocoa](https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa/issues/1480)

The bug is still present in XCode6 GM and so XCode6 final release:

> Well, I get the exact same issue in xcode6GM no matter whether I
>   create framework for swift OR objc :-[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[

According to [Apple Extension Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionScenarios.html):

You can make a containing app available to users running iOS 7 or earlier, but then must take precautions to safely link embedded frameworks when running in iOS 8 or later.

talking about app extensions, but if you read it, you can understand that this applies to embedded frameworks in general.

Answer (score 0):

After using XCode 6.1.1 I am able to put the code on iOS 8+ iOS7.1.2 and iOS 6.1.3
Although the warning is still there but the app works absolutely fine on all the 3 OSs

Yes not able to submit the app for review.
Had to do by changing the modern frameworks to Static libs.

Comment: But you will not be able to submit the App for review!

Answer (score 0):

this is happening because one of your embedded binaries's deployment target is lower than your applications target. lower your embeded binaries's building target and be fine.

this was the error cause in xcode 6.1.1

i was using xcglogger with deployment target ios 8.0, and my application's deployment target 7.0. set the xcglogger's deployment target ios 7.0 and problem solved.