# Error when debugging on 7.1 device swift xcode6 beta 3

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a project that worked fine in beta2 but now it's broken with the following runtime error.

```
dyld: Symbol not found: __TWPVSs26AutoreleasingUnsafePointerSs8_Pointer
  Referenced from: /var/mobile/Applications/6A8ABF68-4B3D-464A-9322-3B3F61B429E2/MovieLookUp.app/MovieLookUp
  Expected in: /private/var/mobile/Applications/6A8ABF68-4B3D-464A-9322-3B3F61B429E2/MovieLookUp.app/Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib
 in /var/mobile/Applications/6A8ABF68-4B3D-464A-9322-3B3F61B429E2/MovieLookUp.app/MovieLookUp
```

I have changed all arrays etc. to the new standard (got nice warnings and autocorrection boxed for them). I'm pretty new to iOS coding so I need some guidance that might give me a  better clue at this matter.

I still have a warning and get the same problem as mentioned in: [relocatable dylibs (e.g. embedded frameworks) are only supported on iOS 8.0 and later (@rpath/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622495/relocatable-dylibs-e-g-embedded-frameworks-are-only-supported-on-ios-8-0-and)

Thanks!

Comment: What class type does the AutoreleasingUnsafePointer point to? If it's a custom class, what does it inherit from?

Comment: I'm getting the same error.  It happens even if I create a new swift application, make no changes and then try to run the app.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was getting the same error and I solved it by:

1. Opening the organizer in XCode 6 Beta3 (Window -> Organizer)
2. Selecting the "Projects" tab at the top
3. Selecting my project in the left hand side column
4. Selecting the "Delete..." button next to the Derived Data location

My swift application now runs on iOS 7.1.2 on my iPhone 4

Answer (score 5):

I solved this by deleting the cached files in `../DerivedData/*` and `~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode`

Answer (score 2):

cleaning DerivedData folder resolves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `import Foundation` to the first line of my `AppDelegate.swift` file (Xcode 6 Beta 3)