# dyld: Symbol not found: __TMdVSs20_DisabledRangeIndex_ xcode 6 beta 4

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

When ever i compile and run on my device(running iOS beta 4) i receive this error:

dyld: Symbol not found: __TMdVSs20_DisabledRangeIndex_
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EE83D921-D691-4E98-8A20-152A3DF99FFA/APPNAME.app/APPNAME
  Expected in: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EE83D921-D691-4E98-8A20-152A3DF99FFA/APPNAME.app/Frameworks/libswift_stdlib_core.dylib
 in /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/EE83D921-D691-4E98-8A20-152A3DF99FFA/Playlists.app/APPNAME

But when ever i run it on the simulator i get this error:

Warning: Error creating LLDB target at path '/Users/????/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APPNAME-fcobcqewkjjsfwdhygjjrmuaxmaf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/APPNAME.app'- using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from remote devices.

Everything works fine on beta 3.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try doing a Clean then rerun. That worked for me.

If that doesn't work:

1. Clean
2. In Organizer window, pick your app and click Delete Derived Data
3. Delete the app on your device
4. Try again

Comment: That did not work for me. :-( It definitely seems to be project-dependent, as breakpoints are working for me in other projects. So aside from the Derived Data directory and the compiled code and the simulator, are there any other places I should look to clean out?

Comment: Followup: deleted ~/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24623831/error-when-debugging-on-7-1-device-swift-xcode6-beta-3?rq=1 and still have the issue.